# add green background to the label that contains the selected radio input

Tags: angularjs

I am new at angular. I would like that by clicking on the selected radio input, the label turns green. How can I do it?

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div>Which one?</div>
        <label class="radio" ng-repeat="eval in evaluators">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="cell.evaluator" name="evaluatorOptions" value="{{eval.name}}">{{eval.name}}
        </label>
            <hr />
        <div>You picked: {{cell.evaluator}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cell = {
        evaluator: "Guava2"
    };
    $scope.evaluators = [{
        name: "Guava1"
    }, {
        name: "Guava2"
    }];


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/77axwybr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-class to dynamically set the class of the label using a method on scope that checks the current value with that set in ng-model.

```
<style>
 .selected {
  background: green;
 }
</style>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div>Which one?</div>
        <label ng-class="{selected: isSelected(eval.name) }" class="radio" ng-repeat="eval in evaluators">
            <input type="radio" ng-model="cell.evaluator" name="evaluatorOptions" value="{{eval.name}}">{{eval.name}}
        </label>
            <hr />
        <div>You picked: {{cell.evaluator}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isSelected = (name) => $scope.cell.evaluator === name;

    $scope.cell = {
        evaluator: "Guava2"
    };
    $scope.evaluators = [{
        name: "Guava1"
    }, {
        name: "Guava2"
    }];
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vsdvcepn/

Comment: thanks, can you explain me that line please?  (name) => $scope.cell.evaluator === name;

Comment: it's an es6 arrow function equivalent to

$scope.isSelected = function(name) {
 return $scope.cell.evaluator === name;
}

Comment: sorry posted the answer before i finished, didn't realise it submitted when i hit enter. I can update the code example if it makes it clearer for you.